# How can i execute command "pip install " with concatenating with array element in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have an array with Python modules names. I want to iterate over array elements and for each element in the array I want to execute command `pip install`. Getting error with line

`pip install  + $modules[$i]`

Here is how my code looks like.

```
$modules = "urllib", "pandas", "selenium", "requests", "numpy"

for($i=0; $i -lt $modules.length; $i++) {
    pip install  + $modules[$i]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what worked for me

& "pip" install $($modules[$i])

Answer (score 0):

Use ampersand operator `&` to execute commands and pass arguments to them:

```
& "pip" "install $($modules[$i])"
```

Comment: getting an error that "pip install urllib" is not recognized as a command

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your script,changed the logic and you should have error handling where you should be knowing if any of the modules are failing to install.

```
$modules = @("urllib", "pandas", "selenium", "requests", "numpy")

    foreach($module in $modules)
    {
    try{
        pip install $module
        }
    catch
        {
        "Error in installing the module: $module"
        $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
```

However, for `URILIB`, the supported version compatibility should be taken into consideration.

If the path variables are configured properly and pip is installed successfully(can test that directly in cmdline), then the above script will work. I tested it in my local and all the modules installed properly(excluded numpy though).

Hope it helps.